# PHP foreach over JSON with Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json return that looks like this:

```
[output] => stdClass Object
    (
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Email] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test1@AOL.COM
                        [1] => test2@AOL.COM
                    )

                [PhoneNumber] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2031234569
                    )

            )
```

What i need to do is be able to loop through the phones and emails and get them all.

I have tried:

```
foreach ($json_result->output->data as $data) {
$phone = $data->PhoneNumber;
$email = $data->Email;
}
```

but this is returning empty. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your sample code isn't "returning" anything, it's just a couple of variable assignments. What are you trying to do with `$phone` and `$email`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `PhoneNumber` and `Email` as properties, while they are arrays.

```
foreach ($json_result->output->data->Email as $email_address) {
    echo $email_address;
}

foreach ($json_result->output->data->PhoneNumber as $phone_number) {
    echo $phone_number;
}
```

Comment: `PhoneNumber` and `Email` are properties of the object. They themselves are arrays, but there was nothing wrong with his original code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is JSON encode your std object and then decode it back to an array:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
foreach($array as $data) {
   $phone = $data->PhoneNumber;
   $email = $data->Email;
}
```